# Make gcc not issue a 'ret' instruction at the end of function

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compilation

If I compile this piece of C code:

```
void _start() {
}
```

with this invocation of gcc:

```
gcc -nostdlib -Os -S foo.c
```

I get this assembly listing:

```
        .file   "foo.c"
        .section        .text.unlikely,"x"
LCOLDB0:
        .text
LHOTB0:
        .globl  __start
        .def    __start;        .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
__start:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        popl    %ebp
        ret
        .section        .text.unlikely,"x"
LCOLDE0:
        .text
LHOTE0:
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.9.2"
```

As you see gcc has issued a 'ret' instruction at the end of the code. Is there a way to make it *not* to issue that?

Comment: Why don't you want the `ret`? You realize it has to be there in order to return to whatever called the function?

Comment: You can add an endless loop so it never returns.

Comment: I want control to pass right through the end! This is intended to be used as shellcode. I'm just trying to see if I can write shellcode in C. So I can't have a return, and can't have a loop there either.

Comment: Shellcodes usually terminate, for example by `exec`-ing a shell ;) But the `ret` is going to be the least of your problems, you will probably run into trouble with zero bytes and no data section.

Comment: Why don't you just code everything normally, but then when you generate the shellcode, you just omit from it the last instruction `ret`? It has opcode `0xC3`, you can simply not copy it, or replace it with `nop` (opcode `0x90`).

Comment: @Jester I want to return control to the patched program after the shellcode is run, so my injecter program puts a `jmp` instruction at the end of the shellcode.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist That's certainly an option, but I wanted to know if I can make gcc simply not issue that `ret` instruction. Apparently I can!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling [`__builtin_unreachable();`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) in your function tells gcc that it does not need to return at the end, since it will not reach the end.